# Find equation for the line parallel to given plane and intersect the line k orthogonaly and x-axis

Tags: linear-algebra

Find equation for the line which is parallel  with the plane $$\pi:x+2y-3z=1$$ intersect the line orthogonaly $$k:(x,y,z)=(1+2t, t, -1),t\in\Re$$ intersect x-axis for some point. All these condition must be satisfied at the same time.

Ive been stuck on this one for quiet a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to work out the vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ which is orthogonal to $k$ in General. Equation for $k$: $k=(1,0,-1)+t(2,1,0)$. Hence $(2,1,0)v=0$ because $v$ is orthogonal to the vector which generates the line $(2,1,0)$.

The other components of $v$ you obtain when substituting into the equation of $\pi$.

Then you have the equation for a line (1 Parameter must remain since a line is determined by 1 parameter).

Comment: But the line needs to be parallel with the plane. normal of plane * V=0 and V*(2,1,0)=0 by comparing them I get v=M*(1,-2,-1) how do I go from there?